# jquery remove a tags based on query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of images inside a p tag inside a div

How can I use jquery to remove the `a` tags if `basket=` is equal to one of these `empty`, `semi`, `abandoned` ?

```html
<div id="userShop">
  <p class="shoppingbaskets">
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=empty"><img src="image/empty.png" title="empty" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=full"><img src="image/full.png" title="full" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=semi"><img src="image/semi.png" title="semi" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=abandoned"><img src="image/abandoned.png" title="abandoned" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=completed"><img src="image/completed.png" title="completed" width="50" height="50"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) is useful here

```js
$("#userShop a").each(function(link) {
  if (["empty","semi","abandoned"].indexOf(
       new URL(this.href).searchParams.get("basket")
     ) !=-1) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userShop">
  <p class="shoppingbaskets">
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=empty"><img src="image/empty.png" title="empty" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=full"><img src="image/full.png" title="full" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=semi"><img src="image/semi.png" title="semi" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=abandoned"><img src="image/abandoned.png" title="abandoned" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=completed"><img src="image/completed.png" title="completed" width="50" height="50"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`href` is an atribute,so you can use it via attribute selector and use `$` to match if it ends with your parameter

```js
var params = ["empty","semi","abandoned"];
for(var i in params){
 $("a[href$='basket=" + params[i] + "']").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userShop">
  <p class="shoppingbaskets">
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=empty"><img src="image/empty.png" title="empty" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=full"><img src="image/full.png" title="full" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=semi"><img src="image/semi.png" title="semi" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=abandoned"><img src="image/abandoned.png" title="abandoned" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=completed"><img src="image/completed.png" title="completed" width="50" height="50"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not testing against a list

Comment: @mplungjan yeah,the user can pass parameter come from the list

Comment: @mplungjan let me try now

Comment: And `for...in` is not used for arrays. - instead use `for (var i=0;i<params.length;i++)`

Comment: @mplungjan yeah my solution is only work if the parameter is the last,thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

**Hide elements with value contained in attribute**

```
$("a[href*='basket=empty']").hide();
$("a[href*='basket=semi']").hide();
$("a[href*='basket=abandoned']").hide();
```

**Remove elements with value contained in attribute**

```
$("a[href*='basket=empty']").remove();
$("a[href*='basket=semi']").remove();
$("a[href*='basket=abandoned']").remove();
```

Comment: this is a great clean answer, but maybe the OP needs `remove`

Comment: It is clean but possibly not so performant since it has to parse the DOM 3 times

Answer (score -2):

You could use the `.html()` property and rewrite all the content of the parent div "userShop", some like this:

```
if(yourcondition){
$("#userShop").html(".............all the new content.......");
}
```

Comment: Why rewrite the complete content? also `yourcondition` was OP's issue in the first place.

Comment: ohh i see, everyday we learn something new, thanks for the feedback.